# How to compare LDA to other topic models?

Tags: data-mining, data-science, topic-modeling

I am interested in the field of topic modelling and I am about to develop my own algorithm. The problem I am facing at the moment is how to compare the results of my work with the results of state-of-the art models such as LDA. Since the results of the LDA are non-deterministic (to the best of my knowledge they can not be set to be the same if the algorithm is run a second time), how could I draw a conclusion about how good my model is compared to the LDA model using different configuration sets?

Answer (score 0):

Run several times, and report the best and average results.

That is the standard approach to handle random starting conditions.

As long as the spread of the results is not too large, this will still support some conclusions.